# Ember force template sync before longer operation

Tags: ember.js

I have some actions that take some time and I wan't to indicate that to the user by showing a loading spinner. I know realized that sometimes the longer running action is directly triggered before the loading spinner is shown:

```
        this.set('betRound.isLoading', true);
        var _this = this;
        Ember.run.sync();
        Ember.run.later(function(){
            _this.transitionToRoute('betround.edit', _this.get('betRound.content'));
        }, 50);
```

I tried to achieve this by delaying the transition with 50ms, but on some slower mobile devices, the loading spinner that depends on "isLoading" is not shown.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built in loading mechanism?

Comment: you mean the model hook? Or which "built in" functionality are you refering to? I want to show the old route until new one is ready, but want to indicate a spinner in the meantime. In this particular case I don't want to enter a loading subroute, since I want to show the old one as long as i can.

Comment: I am referring to the loading sub route.  The slowness is just the template being rendered to page, correct?  You aren't waiting on any async request to return

Comment: Thats right, the slowness is coming from heavy computed properties and rendering. That is why I went with this "ugly workaround".

Answer (score 0):

I would go with some kind of callback mechanism, where you'd put your loading spinner in a view or component and notify the controller when DOM is ready. Here's an example of a Mixin you can attach to any view or component to make it send a notice after it loads.

```
App.LoadAware = Ember.Mixin.create({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this._super();
    var target = this.get("loadedNoticeTarget");
    Ember.assert("We must have loadedNoticeTarget in LoadAware component or view", target);
    target.send("loadAwareLoaded");
  }
});
```

You would then apply it like this:

```
App.LoadingSpinnerComponent = Ember.Component.extend(App.LoadAware);
```

In your template:

```
{{#if isLoading}}
  {{loading-spinner loadedNoticeTarget=this}}
{{/if}}
```

And then, in your controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    goToSlowRoute: function () {
      this.set("_waitingForSpinner", true);
      this.set("isLoading", true);
    },
    loadAwareLoaded: function () {
      Ember.assert("We must be waiting on spinner at this point", this.get("_waitingForSpinner"));
      this.set("_waitingForSpinner", false);
      this.transitionToRoute("slowRoute");
    }
  },
  isLoading: false
});
```

In this example, you would initiate transition by sending `goToSlowRoute` message to the controller. Full JSBin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xatigoba/2/edit).

Comment: This seems to be working, but I experience randomly that the transition never occurs. Maybe because the assert condition is not met? Although I have not fully understood why you need the _waitingForSpinner. Since I will render it as dependend on isLoading and loadAwareLoaded is triggered as soon as its rendered.

Comment: Yeah in your case, you can remove `_waitingForSpinner` and just use `isLoading`. The former is more a general pattern, useful if you want to call spinner for other things as well. Check console to see if an assert has failed.